# Сегменты и переходы ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте ,
Объясните пожалуйста и поправьте пожалуйста если неправильно.
Что такое сегмент ? 
Насколько я понимаю это просто условный участок оперативный памяти отведенный под определенные нужды . 
Возникло пару вопросов .

1.Каким образом выбирается участок для расположение того или иного    сегмента в памяти , допустим ,    сегмент кода , данных ?
2. Какой размер сегмента и как он выбирается .
3. Что такое переходы ? Дальние и ближние ? 
4. Почему джамп можно сделать только на -127 или +128 битй
5. При вызове процедур тоже есть дальние или ближние переходы ? Если    процедура располагается в сегменте    кода ,то какое ограничение по размеру    ?Зачем вообще осуществлять    внесегментные переходы , нельзя ли    расположить данные в одном сегменте ?

6.Если можно приведите картинку расположения сегментов в памяти и как    переходы осуществляются ?

Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 2):

1,2 - не знаю каким образом, но их местоположение в финальном производимом им же файле выбирает линкер. Зависит от многих факторов: формата исполнимого файла (elf, PE32), целевой среды и т.п.

1. Переход - это переход. Т.е. вы буквально указываете процессору, что нужно совершить переход на такой-то адрес в памяти, по условию (содержимое регистра EAX меньше единицы), или без оного. Ну, а дальний переход - это, насколько мне помнится, из терминологии x86, это такой переход, который позволяет совершить "прыжок" на более удаленные от команды перехода адреса.
2. Не все джампы можно совершать на такие короткие диапазоны. Есть и шире. Пример тому те самые дальние переходы.  Тут все зависит от кода инструкции. Сколько в ней бит выделено под поле адреса\смещения для перехода. Если 8, то да, знаковый оффсет больший\ меньший нежели -127+128 навряд ли удастся задать.
3. А в чем проблема совершить межсегментный переход? Разные сегменты могут распологаться в разных страницах памяти (при страничной модели организации памяти), с разными правами доступа. Если это сегмент, где хранятся константы, то наверняка не имеет смысла устанавливать для него права записи.

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент используется плоская модель памяти и сегментов как таковых нет.

2) раньше в 16битных процессорах были сегменты по 64к.

3) У процессора есть спецрегистр (обычно имеет имя IP), в котором храниться адрес "**следующей** инструкции, которую нужно исполнить" (ключевое слово - следующей).

Переход - это просто запись нового адреса в этот регистр. При относительном переходе просто текущее содержимое этого регистра складывается/вычитается с смещением, которое записано в команде. Есть короткие, ближние и дальние переходы. Короткие переходы - это обычно в пределах 256 байт (256 - это максимально, что влазит в один байт). Такие переходы часто очень дешевые - занимают мало места (обычно два байта) и выполняются быстро. Дальние переходы - это обычно по полному адресу. Ближние переходы - в пределах текущего сегмента.

4) потому что -127 .. 128 - это один байт - ровно столько отведено в короткой форме этой команды.

5) А что такое по факту "вызов процедуры"?  Это просто запись текущего адреса в стек и переход по заданному адресу. А ret просто достает с стека число и делает переход по нему. Но ret никак не может проверить, что в стеке именно адрес и этот адрес туда поместил вызов call.

> Если процедура располагается в сегменте кода ,то какое ограничение по размеру

а где же ей ещё располагаться? Ограничение по размеру - а нет его. Нет в коде процедур. Это просто набор байт.

> Зачем вообще осуществлять внесегментные переходы , нельзя ли расположить данные в одном сегменте

учитывая, что раньше сегменты были по 64к, а код мог быть больше, то такие переходы нужны. Можно конечно в несколько приемов переходить, но смысл?

6) картинку? Вы программируете под 16битный процессоры? в современных 32битных процессорах сегмент на 4 гигабайта (если я правильно помню).

Comment: p.s. я понял, что Вы путаете сегменты процессора и сегменты (секции, если быть точнее) в исполнимом файле.